# What is an affordable monitor compatible with HDMI and Ubuntu?

Tags: monitor, hdmi

My main computer is a laptop and I would like to buy an external, bigger monitor for it. I already tried one, but it only had a normal VGA connection. Unfortunately the screen flickered a lot, and I suspect that this was because my notebook's VGA port does not deliver enough power.

That is the reason why I want to buy a monitor which I can use with my HDMI port. Is this properly supported with Ubuntu? Can I buy any screen I like that has an HDMI plug? Or do you have to avoid certain products?

Comment: I'd say it's much more likely that it just wasn't set up correctly than it being a fault of VGA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu should be compatible with any monitor you buy. I assume you have Ubuntu already installed and the graphics chip is supported.

The VGA problem you had was almost certainly a configuration problem (e.g. wrong/unusable refresh rate), not a hardware problem.

For a big screen (1680x1050 or higher resolution) I would anyway recommend using a digital connection. So either directly HDMI or DVI with a HDMI-to-DVI adapter.

Answer (score -1):

I use Samsung UN40KU6300 and UN40KU7000 40-Inch 4K Ultra HD Smart LED TV.  It performs like an awesome computer monitor but with the price of a TV (

My only issue with Ubuntu and HDMI is if you are using a USB-C HDMI adapter.  Then you might have to try a few adapters to find one that works (with any monitor).  This one from Cable Matters worked for me with a DELL XPS13 Developer Edition:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00X4S5C7G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00X4S5C7G)